# WebDev Product Personalization

Tags: html, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

We are beginners trying to create product personalization experience for our customers. Our website is currently on Wordpress CMS and uses Woo. What we trying to achieve is to offer our customer complete product personalization.

We want to  ask them a series of questions, such as weight , age, etc, as well as to allow them to choose ingredients and flavour to create a personalized food diet. After the questionnaire we want to lead them to  a product page with fully customized product with right ingredients , flavor and image in place.

Closest example to our goal: https://thefarmersdog.com

Where do we start? Are there specific forms we need to use ? How to link  customer input with output on product page.

Please give us something to  start with, so we can further research and learn.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search a plugin for this on Envato Market or Codecanyon with a keyword multi-step form for woocommerce.

Which I already, but I would suggest to create a custom multi-step form scratch that will give you a freedom to check the fields of woocommerce product on the database.

This way the you can redirect the user to the suggested product page depending on the inputs of the user.

Use the ACF Plugin to add custom fields on woocommerce product. Use the values of the custom fields to match with the multi-step form. Then redirect to the product page.

Goodluck with the project. Let me know if you need help. :)

Comment: Thanks so much! And by scratch, do you mean create our own form instead of using  premade plugins? Also, do you know how we can make image dynamic. That is the  product label on the image should  reflect customers name depending on input in forms.

Comment: Yes create your own form. And, yes It will be dynamic. The form will retrieve the product's data from woocommerce which include image, title, description, price, category etc. depending on user inputs.